# In Sublime, typing <tab> after colon causes 'key => "value"' to appear, why?

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3

In Sublime (I'm using Sublime 3), typing  after a colon causes the text 'key => "value"' to appear.

This is an annoying behaviour.

I merely want to indent the text after the colon.

Why is this happening (it must have some key binding as a shortcut)?
And how do I remove this behaviour?

Thank you

Comment: It's a sublime snippet (tabTrigger set to ':' character) present on the javascript package. FileName: Object-key-key-value.sublime-snippet. You can remove it if you want.

Answer (score 6):

Step-by-step instruction:

1. Install [PackageResourceViewer](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/PackageResourceViewer)
2. In the command palette type "*prv*", select "***P***ackage**R**esource**V**iewer: Open Resource"
3. Select your language e.g. "*JavaScript*"
4. Select: "*Snippets/*"
5. Select the 'offender': "*Object-key-key-value.sublime-snippet*"
6. Comment out (use XML/HTML comments, `<!-- -->`, as it is an XML) or just delete the line containing: `<tabTrigger>:</tabTrigger>`
7. Save

Comment: Thank you so much, this was extremely annoying!

Comment: Yes, thank you this was SO annoying. I was searching everywhere for this fix. I even made my own stack overflow question and posted it, but saw this and deleted it. This worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As it's a built in package (as @sergioFC said), you will need to extract the file and create an override. Alternatively, use https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/PackageResourceViewer to open the file, and remove the tab trigger. Upon saving it will place the override file in the proper location.